# Trouble writing basic pseudocode

Tags: algorithm, pseudocode

I need help writing some basic pseudocode.

I have a dataset that contains both *start* and *end* times of taxi trips in minutes (`end_time`, `start_time`). I need help writing some pseudocode that calculates how many of these trips are greater than 1 hour.

The `duration`s are read one at a time and should only be read until the end of file is reached.

Comment: can you provide a sample data in your file?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to write an algorithm for the above problem by taking an example.

Let's say there is a file with `5` entries of `end_time` and `start_time`, something like this:-

```
1. 09:00 am - 10:05 am
2. 11:00 am - 11:15 am  
3. 12:00 pm - 12:30 pm
4. 15:00 pm - 18:00 pm
5. 07:00 am - 07:10 am
```

As there is no sample data provided with the post, I am assuming that the data looks something similar to what I have written above where `first time` is our `start_time` and `second time` is our `end_time`.

Now our algorithm would look something like this:-

```
Step 1. Load the file which has data. Also create a global variable to store count and initialize it to zero.
Step 2. Start Reading the file line by line and store each line in a temporary variable.
Step 3. Parse the line i.e split the line in the above example based on ' ' (space).
Step 4. Once we get the start and end time while parsing the line, calculate the time difference and store this difference in a variable called diff_time.
Step 5. if (diff_time > 1 hour) { count++; }
Step 6. Print the count.
```

Hope this helps!